# ng-repeat not updating on array update - Angular Chosen

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-chosen

I have a select box to which I have applied angular-chosen. Below is the full HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller="mainController">
        <div ng-init="init()">
            <select id="selectid1" name="selectid1" ng-model="angularselect" chosen>
               <option value=""></option>
               <option ng-repeat="report in reportValuesOptions" value="{{report['value']}}">{{report['name']}}</option>
            </select> Value : {{angularselect}}
       </div>
       <input type="button" ng-click="addreport()" value="Add Report" />
    </div>
</body>
```

The select box is getting populated from an array in controller scope `$scope.reportValuesOptions = [];`

There is a `init` function which is called on `div` load to set default values in `select` box

```
 $scope.init = function()
  {
    $scope.reportValuesOptions.length = 0;
    $scope.reportValuesOptions.push({'name':'Previous day compasite','value':'previousdaycomposite'});
  $scope.reportValuesOptions.push({'name':'ACH Customer Activity','value':'achcustomeractivity'});
  }
```

There is a `button` in HTML which calls the `addReport` function when clicked to add values in array `$scope.reportValuesOptions`

But on clicking this `button`, values added to array, are not reflected in `select` box. Those values should also be available to `select` box as its `option`

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/rt5yxd74/3/)**

Comment: Don't **EVER** set the length of an array yourself

Comment: See [this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/rt5yxd74/4/)

Comment: I was setting its `length` to 0 to avoid duplication of values.